# Overlay "Winner of the month" image over another image using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

For ex, I have an image Projector.jpg http://lieblingskoeder.umatechcorner.com/imgsample/Projector.jpg

First i display this with a specific size in my gallery. There are several images displayed like this.

One of such images should be tagged as "Winner of the month". To do this, I have another transparent image WinnerOfTheMonth http://lieblingskoeder.umatechcorner.com/imgsample/winnerofthemonth.png. I need to display this image in top-left corner of projector.jpg.

Is it possible to achieve this using CSS? can someone help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put both images in a div
2. Give the div `position:relative`
3. Give the winner of the month image a `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rqX8W/)**